# Needed explation on voltage regulator

Tags: transistors, resistors, diodes, zener

[image]

the below is connected as, the positive part of zener diode is connected to battery of the negative and positive part of zener diode is connected to base of the transistor and one of the resistor is connected to base through emitter and another resistor is connected base through zener diode positive. and collector is free end.
and i wanted to know its working as voltage regulator.

Comment: So your battery discharges permanently through 20 ohms. How is the positive of the zener connected to the positive of the battery?

Comment: Transistor is flipped left to right on schematic. Also resistor values make no sense.

Comment: Where did you get this circuit from ? If you got it from a source, please provide a link to it. How was the resistor values decided ?

Comment: There are some glaring errors in your text and the schematic, Please edit.

Answer (score 1):

The base-collector junction will act as a forward biased diode, so if the zener voltage is less than 5V (the unloaded potential of the resistive divider), the base will be at the zener voltage, and the collector about 0.7V less.

Thus, for a very light load, and a Zener below 5V, there will actually be some voltage regulation at the output of this utterly crazy circuit!

But increase the load current and it will lose regulation again as the base voltage falls below the zener voltage.

Of course if the zener is much less than 5V, the transistor B-E junction will operate in reverse breakdown, helping to maintain the zener voltage, at least, until the transistor fails.